# retrieving results from mySQL using options from selected check boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple form in PHP, having 4 check boxes. The user can select 0-4 number of checkboxes and based on their selection the results should differ.

Basically the four checkboxes represents the four campuses of a university- Campus A,B,C,D. and suppose if the user select 2 campuses say A and C. then I want to query the database based on the selection and retrieve the courses corresponding to those two campuses A and  C. If the user selects only one campus then I want to retrieve courses in that single campus.

On mySQL, I have a Location table with the following schema (ID,Campus Name, City, State) with ID being the primary key. Also I have a course table with schema as Course(ID,CourseName,LocationID,Seatsleft). ID is the primary key and LocationID is the foreign key, which references ID of Location table.

My PHP code is as follows:

Here is the updated version of my code.

PHP form check box selecting different campuses

```
<body>

<?php
require 'connection.php';


    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit'])) 
    {
        $aCampus = $_POST['campus'];



        if(empty($aCampus)) 
        {
            echo("<p>You didn't select any campus.</p>\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
            $N = count($aCampus);

            echo("<p>You selected $N campus(s): ");
            for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
            {
                echo($aCampus[$i] . " ");
            }
            echo("</p>");
        }

    }

    function IsChecked($chkname,$value)
    {
        if(!empty($_POST[$chkname]))
        {
            foreach($_POST[$chkname] as $chkval)
            {
                if($chkval == $value)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    $where="1";

    if(!empty($_POST['campus'])){
    foreach ($_POST['campus'] as $campus){

       $where=" LocationID='". $campus."'";
       }
    }

//$query = "SELECT `Name` FROM `course` WHERE LocationID=1";
$query="SELECT `Name` FROM  `course` WHERE 1 AND (".$where.")";


if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {

while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

$coursename =$query_row['Name'];
echo $coursename. '<br/>';

}
} else {
echo mysql_error();

}



?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        Which campus courses do you want to get access to?<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="campus[]" value=1 />Campus A<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="campus[]" value=2 />Campus B<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="campus[]" value=3 />Campus C<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="campus[]" value=4 />Campus D

    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

My question is how do I take options from my PHP form and query the database to retrieve  courses from the selected campuses only?

Comment: You should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Answer (score 2):

Please try with following simple query creator logic.

```
    $whereArr =Array();
    $whereArr[] = 1;
    if(!empty($_POST['campus'])){
    foreach ($_POST['campus'] as $campus){
        $whereArr[]="  LocationID LIKE ',". $campus.",'";
       }
    }
   $query="SELECT `Name` FROM  `course` WHERE 1 AND(".implode(" OR ",$whereArr)." )";
```

Above code will work for following record:

```
289,"Math","2,3,",67
```

Comment: Bad example.  Is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string for injection attacks

Comment: Hey Uttam it kind of works for single selections! but not retreving courses when multiple campuses are selected!

Comment: Hey @UttamKadam ! Thanks for your input. Look at the updated version of my code..

Comment: $whereArr =Array();
    $whereArr[] = 1;
    if(!empty($_POST['campus'])){
    foreach ($_POST['campus'] as $campus){
        $whereArr[]="  LocationID='". $campus.",'";
       }
    }
   $query="SELECT `Name` FROM  `course` WHERE 1 AND(".implode(" OR ",$whereArr)." )";

Comment: I have update  code also please confirm that your location are stored by "," like "2,3,". Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Then above code will work for you. also make sure at LocationID's must be like 1,2,3,4, instead of 1,2,3,4 add "," at the last.

Comment: I think there is a syntax error.. Inclusion of the above snippet turns everything below to grey. Its confusing when the code is not ormatted. Why ahould I add comma at the last. LocationID is the foreign key in Course table which corresponds to the primary key ID in Location table.

Comment: I added "," for match. please look at the modified line  $whereArr[]="  LocationID LIKE ',". $campus.",'";

Answer (score 1):

In this instance I would store the campuses as a comma delimited string in the database. Then you can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function in mySQL to query based on that

for instance

a record for the course

```
203,"Biology","1,2,4",34
```

then you can

```
SELECT * FROM course WHERE FIND_IN_SET(4,locationid)
```

which will give you all of the records that have `4` in the "set"

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
$validoptions = array('A','B','C','D');
$allvalid = true;
foreach ($_POST['campus'] as $campus){ 
    if (!in_array($campus,$validoptions)) $allvalid = false;
}
if (!$allvalid) {
    echo 'Wrong campuses selected. Try again.';
    exit;
}
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `Courses` WHERE ';
$query .= 'LocationID = \''.implode('\' OR LocationID = \'',$campuses).'\'';
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$res = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
if ($res && mysql_num_rows()) {
     $data = array();
     while($d = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
         $data[] = $d;
     }
}
if (count($data) > 0) {
    echo 'No courses found !';
}else {
    echo 'Courses found : ';
    print_r($data);
}
```